# SQL TO CYPHER QUERIES

Tags: neo4j

Manager wants to know about details of all the customers and their orders whose order status is delivered.
SQL Query
SELECT *
FROM sOrder
INNER JOIN
Customer ON sOrder.Cust_id = Customer.Cust_id
WHERE sOrder.status = 'Delivered';

How to convert this into cypher.Anyone has got idea?Thanks

Tried to convert sql queries to cypher queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your graph model right.
Most likely customers and orders are separate nodes, so you would end up with something like:

```
MATCH (c:Customer)-[:HAS_ORDER]->(o:Order)
WHERE o.status = 'Delivered'
RETURN *
```